# Prediction on CNN model using lists and generators

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have two CNN architectures, `model_a` and `model_b`. First, I predict the results with the validation set in `model_a`. This works perfectly and takes less than 20 seconds.

The problem is when trying to predict using `model_b`. The tricky thing is that I only want to predict the images that `model_a` has predicted as cats. To do this, I read the labels from the prediction of the  `model_a` and if it's the "cat" label I insert the corresponding image in the list `list_pred_cat`.

However, when I try to do predict `model_b` using `list_pred_cat` it takes ages to run(I stopped counting after 10 minutes) taking longer than `model_a`, which doesn't make sense because it has fewer images to predict. Can it be due to the non-usage of the generator? What can I do to fix this?

PS: Although it takes forever it doesn't return an error.

This is my code:

```
val_generator = val_dataGen.flow_from_directory(directory="./model_a/model_a/val_pad_cc",
                                                    class_mode="categorical",
                                                    batch_size=32,
                                                    shuffle = False, seed = 2)

val_generator.reset()

#loads model_a's weights
model_a.load_weights('/content/Best_weigths_DenseNet121_model_a_teste6.h5')

#predicts model_a results using generators
pred_a=model_a.predict(val_generator)
y_pred_a = np.argmax(pred_a, axis=1)

#Code to transform val_generator into the list x_val
x_val=[]
for i in range(159):
    a , b = val_generator.next()
    x_val.extend(a)

#creates a list containing only the images predicted as cats by model_a
for i in range(5069):
    #label=cat
    if(y_pred_a[i]==0): 
        list_pred_cats.extend(x_val[i])

#loads model_b's weights
model_b.load_weights('/content/Best_weigths_DenseNet121_model_b_teste6.h5')

pred_b=model_b.predict(list_pred_cats)
```

EDIT: I think you also need how I made the models:

```
def create_Densenet(no_classes):
    Resnet = DenseNet121(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
    model = tf.keras.Sequential(Resnet)
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=no_classes, activation="softmax"))

    return model

model_a=create_Densenet(2)
model_b=create_Densenet(2)
```

EDIT2: If I try to put x_val[0](just the first image) in the place of list_pred_cat(`pred_b=model_b.predict(x_val[0], verbose=1)`), it gives me the following error:

`ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer sequential_2: expected shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(32, 256, 3)`

Comment: since there's no error, have you tried running it with GPU instead?

Comment: See if it speeds up the process and give u a result or return some sort of error.

Comment: I am running the program with the COLAB platform using their GPU.

Comment: I really don't understand what's wrong because `model_b` has to predict less images and it takes longer than `model_a`, that makes no sense

Comment: Try with smaller networks so you can debug this. Note that if you are running two models in parallel, this can slow down the execution because of ressources being shared between the two models.

Comment: mind sharing your h5 file ? maybe i can taka a try

Comment: Hm sorry but how do I share a file here?

Comment: to make sure model_b is working correctly use it to predict on the val_generator first. If that works then there is something wring with the  input data. What is .ist_pred_melano? Should it be list_pred_cats

Comment: It should be list_pred_cat instead of list_pred_melano. Sorry my mistake. I have tested it already. Model b is working properly if inserted with the val_generator. So the problem must be on the input data? But it doesn't give an error. @GerryP

Answer (score 1):

you have a batch size of 32 in the generator and in the loop you with next you get 254 batches so 32 X 254 = 8128 images are in x_val. so you then predict 8128 images using model a. Then you iterate only through 5069 of the predictions and if the predicted label was 0  you store the image in list_pred_cats. That all looks correct. What is the shape of list_pred_cats? If about half the image are cats it would be on the order of 2500 images.
These are  not being feed by a generator. You did not set a batch size in model.predict so it defaults to 32. So it would take on the order of 2500/32 steps to complete which is about 78. When you run model.predict set verbose=1. You should see a progress bar which might help you to see what is going on.

Comment: Oh it is a typo. I've corrected it in my code as well. It doesn't change anything though. The list_pred_cat is not the size it should be! I didn't notice that. It should be around 2500 and it is 1297664. `x_val`is 5069 so that part is correct. SO it means the creation of the list_pred_cat is done wrong. But how do I correct it? @Gerry P

Comment: try replacing extend with append

Comment: It doesn't work. The error is is: ValueError: Layer sequential_1 expects 1 input(s), but it received 3523 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(32, 256, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(32, 256, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:2' shape=(32, 256, 3) dtype=float32>,(...)